# How to (properly) type a Form with Typescript (and no external libraries)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms

I'm trying to create a simple typed form and I'm struggling into telling Typescript what values I'd like my inputs to have. So far what I've seen when looking for an answer are a bunch of libraries and custom-made hooks that handle all of it under the hood, but nothing that would do it without the help of external libraries. Hope someone around here has a suggestion.

I want to have a basic auth form where I'm getting the username, email and password from users. As I need to let Typescript know that I'm expecting from the `onChange` callback only a certain set of keys, I've extended `HTMLInputElement` into my custom type. However this seems not to be a correct approach, as then I'm unable to provide my `onChange` handler to the respective `input` callback of the form. Does anybody know how to **properly type** (without `as <>` `as unknown as <>` or specific libraries) a form of this kind? Thanks!

My code:

```js
interface ISignUpState {
    username: string;
    email: string;
    passwordOne: string;
    passwordTwo: string;
    error: string;
}

interface InputProps extends InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
    name: keyof ISignUpState;
    value: ISignUpState[InputProps["name"]]
}

const INITIAL_STATE: ISignUpState = {
    username: '',
    email: '',
    passwordOne: '',
    passwordTwo: '',
    error: ''
}

export const SignUpForm = () => {

    const [state, setState] = React.useState(INITIAL_STATE);

    const onSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {

    }

    const onChange = (event:React.ChangeEvent<InputProps>) => {
        setState(prevState => ({...prevState, [event.target.name]: event.target.value}))
    }

    const {username, email, passwordOne, passwordTwo, error} = state;

    return (
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <input name="username"
            value={username}
            onChange={onChange}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Full Name"/>
        </form>
    )
}
```

And Typescript is complaining about `onChange`:

```
Type '(event: React.ChangeEvent<InputProps>) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
    Type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEvent<InputProps>'.
      Type 'HTMLInputElement' is not assignable to type 'InputProps'.
        Types of property 'name' are incompatible.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"username" | "email" | "passwordOne" | "passwordTwo" | "error"'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript does not integrate the type of the `name` prop into the value at `event.target.name` - all it'll be able to say is that such a value is a `string`, which can't be used where a key of `ISignUpState` is expected (which is more narrow). So the `React.ChangeEvent<InputProps>` isn't usable - you'll have to use  `ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>`, as TS says is required.

```
const onChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [event.target.name]: event.target.value }));
};
```

You might think that the `event.target.name` there, typed as just a string, is weird, since it's not typed as a key of `ISignUpState` - but TypeScript accepts it.

If TypeScript *didn't* accept it, you could use a type assertion or narrow the type before combining the object (maybe log an error if type narrowing fails) - but it's not needed.

Comment: And here I was thinking I should narrow it down more, and the basics worked... Thanks a lot for your answer @CertainPerformance - that does solve it, and well explained as well!